# Upon booting up an old laptop with Linux Mint, I get "This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU"

Tags: linux, boot, system-installation, boot-loader

Recently, I have been given an old laptop and I wanted to see if I could get it to work, and so that I didn't need to by windows, I decided to use linux for my first time. I am using a driver to boot linux, and I can get onto a screen that will give me the option to run linux, run linux in compatibility mode, ect and then, whether I click on compatibility mode or normal it chunters for a bit and then it says:

> This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU. Unable to boot – please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU

My computer is a Compaq nc4200 and here is the link to the specs:  https://www.cnet.com/products/hp-nc4200/specs/ and I have tried each type of Mint (Cinnamon, MATE, Xfce).

If I could be given any help on this problem then I would be very great full and I am willing to answer any questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message is pretty straightforward. [Intel Pentium M 740](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/27590/intel-pentium-m-processor-740-2m-cache-1-73-ghz-533-mhz-fsb.html) is a 32-bit instruction set processor, while your kernel requires a 64-bit processor.

[Linux Mint 20](https://linuxmint.com/release.php?id=38) (the latest) only supports 64-bit, but you can go for [Linux Mint 19.3](https://linuxmint.com/release.php?id=36), supported until April 2023 or [Linux Mint Debian Edition](https://linuxmint.com/download_lmde.php).

Of course, one is not limited to Mint, but unfortunately dropping 32-bit support is a trend and your options are likely to decrease over time.

Comment: Some other 32 bit distributions. But a lot of software now is only 64 bit. https://itsfoss.com/lightweight-linux-beginners/ But for some you have to select an older version and only the 32 bit version. Often 64 bit is now default.